# How to make queries with MongoMapper/Ruby?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomapper, nosql

I started using NoSQL with Ruby. Here's the code I have

```
require 'mongo'
require 'mongo_mapper'

class User
  include MongoMapper::Document
end

MongoMapper.connection = Mongo::Connection.new('localhost', 27017)
MongoMapper.database = "mydb"

all_users = MongoUser.where(:age => 1) # WORKS

all_users = MongoUser.where("age > 1") # DOESN'T WORK
```

How can I use ActiveRecord's like where querying? What do I need to do when I need to use <, >, != etc in queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start to read [here](https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/wiki). Mongomapper is build on Datamapper philosophy, so if you want something closer to ActiveRecord try [Mongoid](http://mongoid.org/).

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
all_users = MongoUser.all(:age=>{'$gt'=>1})
```